# How can I forward a port when using PdaNet?

Tags: networking, tethering

I'm using PdaNet to connect my laptop to the Internet. From there I'm using an ethernet cable and Internet conection sharing to connect my PS3 for online gaming. Works pretty good for most games, but one in particular will not connect to the server. I need to know how to adjust the router settings when (I think) the phone is the router. In particular, how can I forward ports and enable UPnP?

If this isn't possible, is there another setup i could use to get what I want? I've got my laptop running Win7 64 bit, a Belkin Play N600 router (not used currently), a stock LG axis AS 740 Android phone (2.1 OS) and the PS3. Oh, and the game I'm trying to play is Modern Warfare 3. I'm just not very tech savvy.

Comment: It's possible that there may not be a way to do this as your cellular carrier could be blocking the port rather than PdaNet (though I couldn't say for certain myself).

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting the question, and existing answers have no upvotes). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical setup with my phone-laptop-xbox. Windows ICS (called Mobile hotspot in Win10) was useless. I got ICS to work for a day or two with my Xbox but gaming on the Xbox was very poor and connections would drop every 5 minutes. Finally after a reboot of my laptop one day Windows wouldn't let me enable Hotspot when using PDAnet as the source of internet. I tried restoring Windows but nothing worked, Windows refused to recognize PDAnet's virtual adapter as a valid internet connection. I tried changing every setting and loading old drivers but Windows kept refusing to acknowledge an internet connection.

After a few hours of experimentation I came across Connectify 2018. Connectify takes the incoming PDAnet internet connection (or any other source of internet) and shares it via the WiFi adapter. It sounds awfully familiar to ICS but one major difference is it allows the WiFi client's connection to be bridged rather than the standard 'routed' mode that ICS only allows. I switched to bridge mode and the UPnP features for the Xbox all worked great and it has never dropped a connection while gaming. Connectify also displays connection details of each client. There are newer and older versions of Connectify but 2018 works flawlessly with Win10, my LG Note and Windows 10. It is available on TBP.